# ViewSet's action decorator is ignoring its permission_classes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Why is my action decorator ignoring its permission_class?

I have a ViewSet that has "IsAuthenticated" for both a generic post/create and for posting to a custom action decorator.

However, when I use the custom action decorator for a non-logged in user, the code for the action decorator still runs (and causes an error).

Why is this? Shouldn't a non-logged in user receive a 401_Unauthorized when posting to the action?

A non-logged in user does receive a 401_Unauthorized when doing a generic post.

Here is the ViewSet:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "pk"
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else:
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    @action(
        methods=["post"],
        detail=True,
        permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated],
        url_name="actioned",
    )
    def actioned(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(user=request.user)
            item.status = "actioned"
            item.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Item.DoesNotExist:
            Item.objects.create(user=request.user, status="actioned")
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I'm using DefaultRouter() for my urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter
router.register(r"items", ItemViewSet, basename="item")
urlpatterns = [ path("", include(router.urls)), ]
```

Here are the tests:

```
# GENERIC POST BY ANONYMOUSUSER DOESN'T RUN AND GIVES 401
def test_public_generic_post(self):
    payload = {"status": None}
    response = APIClient.post(
        reverse("app:item-list"),
        payload,
        format="json"
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED) # True

# ACTION POST BY ANONYMOUSUSER RUNS EVEN THOUGH IT HAS THE SAME IsAuthenticated permission
def test_public_action_post(self):
    item = Item.objects.create()
    response = APIClient.post(
        reverse("app:item-actioned", args=[item.pk]),
        format="json"
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED) # False
```

For the action post, I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot cast AnonymousUser to int. Are you trying to use it in place of User?`

Because it's running my `try: item = Item.objects.get(user=request.user)` code and there is no `request.user`.

But why would it run the action decorator in the first place if the action decorator explicitly has `permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]`?

I can confirm that `request.user.is_authenticated` is `False`.

Comment: Did you try renaming the method decorated with @action? Because the ModelViewSet model has a variable called action which specifies the name of the current action.

Comment: @Tiki ah yes, the method being called "action" is just an example/dummy code. I've gone ahead and renamed it in my original post.

Comment: I suspect from the get_permissions method, can you try to comment it out?

Comment: @KutayAslan yep, that fixed it and I know why my error happened now. I'll update this thread with an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @KutayAslan's comment, removing the get_permissions method resolves this error.

It looks like in my original code, the action decorators were being assigning [AllowAny] due to its "self.action" falling under the "else" clause.

Setting up the permission_classes to explicitly equal the action decorator resolves this issue:

```
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        elif self.action == "actioned":
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else:
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for anyone looking at this thread is that you mis-spelled the `BasePermission` functions as `has_permissions` and `has_object_permissions` (plural) instead of `has_permission` and `has_object_permission` (singular)!